# How to Solve "Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I have this post request to my api that needs an array of json objects like :

```
[{ 
   "x": 1,
   "y": 1
}]
```

My function:

```
Future<String> deleteObstacle(String server, int x, int y) async {
    final response =
        await http.delete(Uri.parse('$server/admin/obstacles/'), headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }, body: [
      jsonEncode(<String, int>{"x": x, "y": y})
    ]);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> launchResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return launchResponse['response'];
    } else {
      throw Exception("ERROR Attempting to Delete obstacle");
    }
  }
```

}

Throws error:

```
"Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
```

Im not sure how to map that body and ive tried an array of things. What approach is better?

Edit:

Full stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/0QNAG7p4)

Comment: What does the error refer to?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @ScottHunter posted the stack trace. Basically call that function when the user wants to delete an object from the world.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
    [{ 
   "x": 1 **as** *int*,
   "y": 1 **as** *int*
}]
```

It tells Flutter what type of data you're inserting. Works for me.

Comment: Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'IdentityMap<String, int>'

is the error when I replace the body with this way

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the error? Is it in the body request? If its, try this for the body part. Hope its help you

```
 Map<String, int> body = <String, int>{
      'x'      : x,
      'y'      : y,
 };
  final response =
        await http.delete(Uri.parse('$server/admin/obstacles/'), headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }, body: jsonEncode(body)
 
  );
```

Comment: this also says expected type int got type string. I had to add square brackets to the body because its expecting an array of json objects.